# syntax error near unexpected token [SOLVED]

Tags: navigation, odometry, c++, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys,

I am new in ros and i am having trouble with the odometry c++ publish turorial (wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom). I am using the code in this link.

When i try to rosrun the program it gives me this:

line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('

line 5: `  int main(int argc, char** argv){'

I don't understand why. BTW i am using groovy.

my c code is:

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <tf/transform_broadcaster.h>
    #include <nav_msgs/Odometry.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "odometry_publisher");


    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Publisher odom_pub = n.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("odom", 50);
    tf::TransformBroadcaster odom_broadcaster;

    double x = 0.0;
    double y = 0.0;
    double th = 0.0;

    double vx = 0.1;
    double vy = -0.1;
    double vth = 0.1;

    ros::Time current_time, last_time;
    current_time = ros::Time::now();
    last_time = ros::Time::now();

    ros::Rate r(1.0);
    while(n.ok()){
        current_time = ros::Time::now();

        //compute odometry in a typical way given the velocities of the robot
        double dt = (current_time - last_time).toSec();
        double delta_x = (vx * cos(th) - vy * sin(th)) * dt;
        double delta_y = (vx * sin(th) + vy * cos(th)) * dt;
        double delta_th = vth * dt;

        x += delta_x;
        y += delta_y;
        th += delta_th;

        //since all odometry is 6DOF we'll need a quaternion created from yaw
        geometry_msgs::Quaternion odom_quat = tf::createQuaternionMsgFromYaw(th);

        //first, we'll publish the transform over tf
        geometry_msgs::TransformStamped odom_trans;
        odom_trans.header.stamp = current_time;
        odom_trans.header.frame_id = "odom";
        odom_trans.child_frame_id = "base_link";

        odom_trans.transform.translation.x = x;
        odom_trans.transform.translation.y = y;
        odom_trans.transform.translation.z = 0.0;
        odom_trans.transform.rotation = odom_quat;

        //send the transform
        odom_broadcaster.sendTransform(odom_trans);

        //next, we'll publish the odometry message over ROS
        nav_msgs::Odometry odom;
        odom.header.stamp = current_time;
        odom.header.frame_id = "odom";
        odom.child_frame_id = "base_link";

        //set the position
        odom.pose.pose.position.x = x;
        odom.pose.pose.position.y = y;
        odom.pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
        odom.pose.pose.orientation = odom_quat;

        //set the velocity
        odom.twist.twist.linear.x = vx;
        odom.twist.twist.linear.y = vy;
        odom.twist.twist.angular.z = vth;

        //publish the message
        odom_pub.publish(odom);

        last_time = current_time;
        r.sleep();
    }
}
```

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97226/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-%5Bsolved%5D/) by [trbf](https://answers.ros.org/users/8366/trbf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-11-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-11-02**:
We need to see the code that you try to compile

**Comment by [trbf](https://answers.ros.org/users/8366/trbf/) on 2013-11-02**:
Ok,sorry about the editing,i don't now why it appears like that!

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-11-02**:
It is because of indentation. It would be better if you shift your code to right by one tab, then paste it here. I'm not sure I understand it correctly but isn't there a problem with your "include"s?

**Comment by [trbf](https://answers.ros.org/users/8366/trbf/) on 2013-11-03**:
Thanks, now it is better. Maybe is the includes but i don't know why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved! I was trying to run de cpp file instead of the one made with the rosmake! It was a really nub problem!

Thanks

---

Originally posted by [trbf](https://answers.ros.org/users/8366/trbf/) with karma: 16 on 2013-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andrea019](https://answers.ros.org/users/27520/andrea019/) on 2016-12-15**:
Hello! I have the same problem :) which file is the one made with the rosmake? :(

**Comment by [trashperson](https://answers.ros.org/users/50716/trashperson/) on 2020-01-25**:
wow I knew I was a noob but I never imagined I was this much of a frikkin n0000b. Thanks for the thread.